# How can I bundle a specific bundle during development in Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

Given these bundles:

```
     public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
     {
        // 3rd party scripts
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/", "*.js"));            

        // my scripts
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/myscripts")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/MyScripts/", "*.js"));
     }
```

During development it would be helpful to bundle just the first bundle, the 3rd party scripts, but not the second.

Is there any way to specify that one bundle shall be bundled and maybe even minified, but the other one not?

I thought about adding something like

```
 BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

but this would bundle all bundles. On the other hand, the bundle classes, like ScriptBundle have no members that would allow me to force their bundling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a transform on the specific bundle, like this :

```
Bundle bundle = new ScriptBundle("~/scripts")
                    .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/", "*.js");
bundle.Transforms.Add(new JsMinify());
bundles.Add(bundle);
```

Comment: this would transform ONLY ~/scripts and not the files added later to thebundle?

Comment: Here the bundle includes all javascript files contained in the scripts/ directory.

Comment: did not test it (the question is a year old) but it looks reasonable. so will mark it as answer.